Nuget Package Re-Targeting In Web form app after upgrading the framework from 4.7 to 4.8.1
I Have Web Forms App projects and i upgraded target framework from 4.7 to 4.8.1 and i want to update nuget packages in same manner, i tried update-package -ProjectName {projectName} -reinstall, but it did not work, i get this error
Failed to update binding redirects for {projectPath} : Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
i tried removing binding redirects from web.config but it does not work either, also tried deleting and installing packages manually but, after installation packets are still targeting 4.7 framework
please if you know some kind of solution or have some ideas help me.
